# how can I use string variable from text input to refer to an array of the same name

Tags: javascript

I have a number of arrays in a javascript file
The array that I want to use in my calculations is:

```
 var planets_num = []
```

If I want to use a certain array, I simply use:

```
  arraytouse = planets_num
```

What I want to do is use an input:

```
 <input type="text" id="mynewtext" value="Enter array name to use">
```

and then a function to get the value of "mynewtext":

```
 function getnewform1 () {
 newtext=document.getElementById('mynewtext').value
 . . .
 }
```

let's say that the var newtext = "abc"
I then want:

```
 abc = planets_num
```

i.e. the values from the array abc to be placed in the planets_num array

Hope this makes sense

TIA

Comment: it's a good idea to use camelCase for naming

Comment: Have you tried using an `eval`.

Comment: Use some object to store the custom values, say `scope`, so you can write `scope[name] = planets_num`

Comment: @btoueg Yes, eval works -> array_name=eval(newtext) along with planets_num=array_name

Answer (score 2):

If `planets_num` is in global scope, you can also refer to it like this:

```
arraytouse = window['planets_num'];
```

Variables on objects are also indexable values on that object by the same name.  For global scope variables, they're on the `window` object.

So you could do something like this:

```
arraytouse = window[document.getElementById('mynewtext').value];
```

If the arrays *aren't* in global scope then you can organize them as properties on some object and reference that object in the same way:

```
arraytouse = objectOfArrays[document.getElementById('mynewtext').value];
```

Comment: Yes arraytouse = window[document.getElementById('mynewtext').value] along with planets_num=arraytouse also works

Answer (score 0):

@David answer is cleaner is more efficient, but here is an alternative with an `eval`:

```
var my_array = [];

$("button")[0].onclick = function()
{
    var input_text = $("input")[0].value;
    var array_input = eval(input_text);
}
```

The fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/W3NW9/3/

Comment: That is a very ugly alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating global variables, you should consider using an object and properties:

```
var data = {
  planets_num: [],
  another_arr:[]
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var arraytouse = data[document.getElementById('mynewtext').value];
```

but of course you should be writing robust code like:

```
var input = document.getElementById('mynewtext');

// Make sure an element was found before trying to access its value
var arraytouse = input && data[input.value];

// Make sure the value resolved to something truthy before
// trying to use it
if (arraytouse) {
  ...
}
```